# Use old javascript befor load page with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have 4 files.
file header.php

```
<br>Header Content from header.php</br></br>
<style>
#menu{font-size:20px;}
#content{font-size:30px;}
</style>
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("a[rel='tab']").click(function(e){
        pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({url:pageurl+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
            $('#content').html(data);
        }});
        if(pageurl!=window.location){
            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);    
        }
        return false;  
    });
});
$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    $.ajax({url:location.pathname+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
    }});
});
</script>
<div id='menu'>
    <a rel='tab' href='http://localhost/Test/ajax/menu1.php'>menu1</a> | 
    <a rel='tab' href='http://localhost/Test/ajax/menu2.php'>menu2</a> | 
    <a rel='tab' href='http://localhost/Test/ajax/menu3.php'>menu3</a>
</div>
```

file menu1.php

```
<?php 
if($_GET['rel']!='tab'){
    include 'header.php';
    echo "<div id='content'>";
}
?>
menu1 content in menu1.php
<?php 
if($_GET['rel']!='tab'){
    echo "</div>";
}?>
```

file menu2.php

```
<?php 
if($_GET['rel']!='tab'){
    include 'header.php';
    echo "<div id='content'>";
}
?>
menu2 content in menu2.php
<?php 
if($_GET['rel']!='tab'){
    echo "</div>";
}?>
file menu3.php
<?php 
if($_GET['rel']!='tab'){
    include 'header.php';
    echo "<div id='content'>";
}
?>
menu3 content in menu3.php
<a href="menu1.php">menu 1</a>
<?php 
if($_GET['rel']!='tab'){
    echo "</div>";
}?>
```

1 run http://localhost/Test/ajax/menu1.php,
link menu1 | menu2 | menu3 -> OK
but
in http://localhost/Test/ajax/menu3.php
i click "menu 1" on body, this not load ajax.

Help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can use `beforeSend` function.

Answer (score 1):

Change the content in menu3.php from

```
<a href="menu1.php">menu 1</a>
```

to

```
<a rel='tab' href='http://localhost/Test/ajax/menu1.php'>menu1</a>
```

Update your js code:

```
$("a[rel='tab']").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
   $('#content').load(pageurl);
   if(pageurl!=window.location){
      window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);    
   }
   return false;
});
```

Comment: I want use with ajax, no load page

Comment: You already have onclick handler, which will load the target url into the **content** element.

Comment: @Nghị -- Read http://api.jquery.com/load/ - it does exactly what you are asking for

Comment: I want send data to server and get data add to #content with ajax